# How to use the same function on each object in the collection using script

Tags: scripting, objects, transforms

How to select objects in the "Cube" collection one by one
Deselect the active one, select the next one from the list and perform x10 scaling operations on it. in script

For example
Cube (selected by me or script)
Scale x10
deselect
select
Cubie.001
Scale x10
deselect
select
Cubie.002
Scale x10
deselect
.....

Cubie.100
Scale x10
deselect

done.
Without loop

Comment: `[setattr(o, "scale", o.scale * 10) for o in bpy.data.collections["Collection"].objects]` ? Although I don't think you can do that without a loop.

Comment: Can u explain us why you don’t want to use a loop? Whatever you will use here - somewhere it will use a loop - else it won’t work. And a while or similar statements are just „other types „ of a loop

Comment: Yes. This scale was only example of function. W wrote this code
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split()
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
To make every face single

Comment: And this one to make project to view face 
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_transform_data_origin = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation(name='Face', use_view=False, use=False, overwrite=True)bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY')
bpy.ops.transform.transform(mode='ALIGN', orient_type='Face')
bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='TOP', align_active=True)

Comment: bpy.ops.uv.project_from_view(orthographic=False, camera_bounds=True, correct_aspect=True, clip_to_bounds=False, scale_to_bounds=False)
bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation()

Comment: But I want doing this w every face in sphere in colletion individual. so why function must finish on first object and start on next one, finish and start to last one object, when in one click all faces on my object will be have project to view individual. and this is target which I need